# Avoid hyphen after @ symbol

Tags: c#, regex, validation, email-validation

I am writing an email validator where I want to validate email such that it doesn't contain hyphen ' _ ' after @ Symbol.
e.g. the email lmn-xyz@abc-pqr.com is allowed but xyz@-pqr.com is not allowed.
I have tried following expression but did not help.

> ^[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+(.[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*.([a-zA-Z]{2,})$

Any suggestion how can I implement above functionality is given regular expression.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add first group again, without hyphen (`[a-zA-Z0-9]`) after `@` sign. To save consistency you should also change `+` with `*` on the first group after `@` - because the added one is required.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+(.[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*(.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+).([a-zA-Z]{2,})$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use negative lookahead after @ symbol:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_\+-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\+-]+)*@(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})$
```